# JavaScript add and removeEventListeners callback with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement parallax with intersectionObserver API which calls eventListener scroll function with callback. The problem is what I want to pass parameter "entry.target" to add and removeEventListener functions, is it possible to remove event listener callback with parameter?.
Currently I have:

```
const parallaxScroll = trg => {
   trg.style.top = `${-trg.getBoundingClientRect().top / 7.3}px`;
}

const addParallax = ([entry]) => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting){
       window.addEventListener('scroll', parallaxScroll);

       //what I want to:
       window.addEventListener('scroll', parallaxScroll(entry.target));
    }else{
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', parallaxScroll);

       //what I want to:
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', parallaxScroll(entry.target));
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you call `addParallax`? If many times, then don't you risk to create many event handlers for scroll that all get executed on a scroll event?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a wrapper function (or call `.bind` to do the same) for each parameter. Assuming that you can have several `entry` objects that each could have an associated active scroll-listener, but not more than one per `entry`, you could dedicate a property of `entry` for storing that listener reference:

```
const addParallax = ([entry]) => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting) {
       if (entry.listener) return; // already have an active listener for this entry
       entry.listener = () => parallaxScroll(entry.target);
       window.addEventListener('scroll', entry.listener);
    } else {
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', entry.listener);
       entry.listener = null;
    }
}
```

Or with `.bind`:

```
const addParallax = ([entry]) => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting) {
       if (entry.listener) return; // already have an active listener for this entry
       entry.listener = parallaxScroll.bind(null, entry.target);
       window.addEventListener('scroll', entry.listener);
    } else {
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', entry.listener);
       entry.listener = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain how to do this with .bind?

Comment: Added the `.bind` variant.